# lazy="true" for many to one equalivalant in hibernate 3

Tags: hibernate

What is the equivalant way to configure lazy="true" in hibernate3.?

While fetching object i will fetch the associated object using fetch concept.So in mapping itself i need to specify it.

Comment: But lazy set to true is default in Hibernate.

Comment: in hibernate 3 by default it is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood the question but if you're looking for an equivalent using annotations, then the `ManyToOne` annotation admits a `fetch` attribute.  From the JPA 1.0 specification:

> #### 9.1.22 ManyToOne Annotation
>
> The ManyToOne annotation defines a
>   single-valued association to another
>   entity class that has many-to-one
>   multiplicity. It is not normally
>   necessary to specify the target entity
>   explicitly since it can usually be
>   inferred from the type of the object
>   being referenced.
>
> Table 15 lists the annotation elements
>   that may be specified for a ManyToOne
>   annotation and their default values.
>
> The cascade element specifies the set
>   of cascadable operations that are
>   propagated to the associated entity.
>   The operations that are cascadable are
>   defined by the CascadeType enum:
>
> ```
> public enum CascadeType { ALL, PERSIST, MERGE, REMOVE, REFRESH};
> ```
>
> The value cascade=ALL is equivalent to
>   cascade={PERSIST, MERGE, REMOVE,
>   REFRESH}.
>
> ```
> @Target({METHOD, FIELD}) @Retention(RUNTIME)
> public @interface ManyToOne {
>   Class targetEntity() default void.class;
>   CascadeType[] cascade() default {};
>   FetchType fetch() default EAGER;
>   boolean optional() default true;
> }
> ```
>
> The EAGER strategy is a requirement on
>   the persistence provider runtime that
>   the associated entity must be eagerly
>   fetched. The LAZY strategy is a hint
>   to the persistence provider runtime
>   that the associated entity should be
>   fetched lazily when it is first
>   accessed. The implementation is
>   permitted to eagerly fetch
>   associations for which the LAZY
>   strategy hint has been specified.

So you can do:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
Foo foo
```

And with Hibernate's XML mappings, the association would be lazy by default.

#### References

- JPA 1.0 specification

  - Section  9.1.22 "ManyToOne Annotation"
- Hibernate Core documentation

  - [5.1.12. Many-to-one](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-manytoone)